# Efficiently removing elements from unit range (Julia)

Tags: performance, julia

I'm trying to efficiently remove a vector of elements `x` from a unit range `1:m` and then return a vector of the remaining elements.

For `length(x)` much smaller than `m`.

Here are the different methods I came up with,

```
using Distributions

function func1(m, x)
    for i in 1:1000
        collect(setdiff(1:m, x))
    end
end

function func2(m, x)
    for i in 1:1000
        filter(n -> !(n in x), 1:m)
    end
end

function func3(m, x)
    dict = Dict(zip(1:m, 1:m))
    for i in 1:1000
        d = copy(dict)
        for n in x
            delete!(d, n)
        end
        collect(keys(d))
    end
end

m = 10000
x = sample(1:m, 100)

@time func1(m, x)
@time func2(m, x)
@time func3(m, x)
```

Function 3 is about twice as fast as functions 1 and 2, however the result isn't sorted, which isn't a deal breaker for me, but I would prefer if the result was sorted.

Because I'm removing elements from a unit range, my intuition tells me that element look up (and deletion) can be made O(1), and thus there should be an algorithm which scales O(len(x)), rather than what I seem to be getting which is O(m) complexity.

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop over 1:1000? It doesn't seem to accomplish anything. If it's there for benchmarking purposes, you should remove it and use BenchmarkTools instead. It's better write the code to do exactly what you need it to do, and *then* make sure that the benchmarking handles repeated evaluations and statistics, which is what BenchmarkTools does for you.

Comment: @DNF yup, it was for benchmarking, good to know about BenchmarkTools, I'll be sure to use it in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `m` is much larger than length of `x` (i.e. you leave most of the elements) then you can consider this:

```
function func4(m, x)
    res = Vector{Vector{Int}}(undef, 1000)
    for i in 1:1000
        ind = trues(m)
        ind[x] .= false
        res[i] = findall(ind)
    end
    return res
end
```

as it should be faster.

(you could be faster if you e.g. knew that `x` is sorted and unique - and maybe in your original problem you know this or again `x` is small enough that sorting it and making unique is almost no cost relative to creation of the result)

I have added `res` on purpose - and I recommend you to add it also in your methods. The reason is that you run at a risk that the compiler notices that your function has no side effects and optimizes out the whole loop as no-op. Here is an example of this happening:

```
julia> function f()
           for i in 1:1_000_000_000
               s = i
           end
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_native f()
    .text
; ┌ @ REPL[163]:2 within `f'
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
    nopl    (%rax,%rax)
; └
```

Comment: This is pretty darn great. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!